# U-Sql for HDinsight not possible

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, u-sql

In Visual Studio Temple for Data Lakes, 
HIVE, Pig, Storm are for HDInsight. But U-Sql is not mentioned to be for HDInsight. Why is that? How can I use U-Sql for HDInsight?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But U-Sql is not mentioned to be for HDInsight. Why is that?

U-SQL runs on [Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-analytics/), not on Hadoop.